# What determines the oauth2 grant type being used?

Tags: oauth-2.0

How does an oauth2 endpoint determine the grant type of a request?

Is it the endpoint itself (i.e. each endpoint is dedicated to one or more grant types). Or is it the list of parameters sent in the request? Or is it the value of the grant_type parameter?

Take anilist.co for example.

Their oauth2 documentation says that for the authorization code grant to use the following endpoint with these parameters:

https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code

For the implicit grant, it says to use this:

https://anilist.co/api/v2/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token

(see: https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/oauth/authorization-code-grant and https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/oauth/implicit-grant)

So it seems like they have one endpoint that determines the grant type based on the response_type value and the presence/absence of the redirect_uri (in other words, grant type is based on parameters).

But is it always this way for every oauth2 provider?

According to this site here:

https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/

… the authorization code and implicit grant types have exactly the same parameter set but are distinguished based on the response_type value (token for implicit, code for authorization code). But the other grant types are distinguished by the grant_type value. Why isn’t every grant type distinguished by the grant_type value?

If I were to guess, therefore, I would say the grant type is determined by the value of grant_type, and where grant_type is missing, it is determined by the value of response_type.

Is this correct? Is this standard across the industry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is determined by the specification RFC [rfc6749]
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

This RFC determines all the endpoints required for OAuth 2.0 implementation.
Its upto the provider on implementation. But, they will have to adhere to the specification for interoperability. Else, proprietary flows may not be able to scale.

In-fact, you can also check the OpenIDConnect specification for further details. (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add here, if you are looking to use OAuth 2.0 with a Native app, there is a different RFC for that i.e. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252

Comment: Thanks to both of you!